# Building SonarQube with maven and batch_boostrap/index cannot be found

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm running mvn sonar:sonar in the directory of the project I'm running.  I already have my pom.xml updated:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
```

After running sudo mvn sonar:sonar (I am on ubuntu 14.04) in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
eschwartz@LATITUDE:~/ideaprojects/xQueryEngine$ sudo mvn sonar:sonar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xQueryEngine (Solr 4 REX) 1.11.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) @ xqe ---
[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.854s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 17 15:56:59 EST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/302M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project xqe: Fail to download libraries from server: Status returned by url : 'http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index' is invalid : 404 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: what's http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index? was it up and running on your machine?

Comment: When setting up SonarQube you have to set a webserver (which is my computer) and a port, by default they are localhost and 9000.  /batch_bootstrap/index is what I don't know, and what my current issue is.

Comment: what's version of sonarqube are you using? It seems to be an old bug

Comment: On my SonarQube dashboard (http://localhost:9000/sonar) it says version 5.3 at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar`. You can do this by passing `-Dsonar.host.url=...` to *mvn*, or ideally set it in your [Maven Global/Project Settings](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings) so that you don't always have to pass it as a command line argument.

Details: if your dashboard is at `localhost:9000/sonar` then it means you're using `sonar.web.context=/sonar` , which is different from the default (`/`). So you need to tell the scanner where to find SonarQube.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean.  sonar.host.url is not a variable in my sonar.properties file.

Comment: Do you mean set sonar.web.host=http://localhost:9000/sonar?  As of right know I left that commented out because I am only using one IP address.

Comment: solved-- in the project that I'm analyzing I changed my prompt to be  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar
and it all worked out.

Comment: Yup that's what I meant. You can (and should) actually do this [in your Maven Global Settings](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings) so that you don't always have to pass it as a command line argument. Answer edited.